# Heat equation with BC, find the steady-state solution

Tags: partial-differential-equations

How can I find steady-state solution in this PDE?

$u_{t} = u_{xx} +u,  \ \ \ \  0<x<L , \ \ t>0$

$u(0,t)=1 , \ \ \ \ \     u(\pi,t)=2, \ \  t>0$

$u(x,0)=sin(3x)$

Solving:

I need to separate into two equations (steady state solution and transient solution) . Suposing that $u(x,t) = w(x,t) + v(x)$ so

$$u_t(x,t) = w_t(x,t) \ \  \text{and} \\   u_{xx}(x,t) = w_{xx}(x,t) + v_{xx}(x)$$

Then $$u_{t} = u_{xx} +u$$

$$w_t = w_{xx} + v_{xx} + w + v = (w_{xx} + w) + (v_{xx} + v)$$

I need that $v_{xx} + v = 0$ and satisfy my BC, so

$$v(0) = 1  \ \ \text{and} \ \  v(\pi) = 2$$

If I choose $v(0) = 1 \rightarrow v(x)= Asin(x) + cos(x)$

If I choose $v(\pi) = 2$ $\rightarrow v(x)= Asin(x) -2cos(x)$

Since I can't get a steady-state equation, I can't separate it into two equations. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: How do you know a steady state exists? It seems to me that here no steady state exists. However, you can still solve the full problem with no decomposition. Try looking at $v=u-(1+x/\pi)$ and seeing what problem that solves.

Comment: If steady state don't exist, I can't use the separation of variables...

Comment: Why not? The real obstacle to separation of variables is the inhomogeneous BC but I just showed you how to get rid of that.

Comment: If I use $v(x) = \frac{x}{\pi} + 1 $ I can solve the problem, but I'm worried about formalization. How did you get this?

When the heat equation ($u_{t}=\alpha^{2}u_{xx}$) has non-homogeneous BC, we can use the formula $v(x)= (T_{2} - T_{1})\frac{x}{L} + T_{1}$. But I do not know if we can use for the problem equation.

Comment: I just made up the linear function satisfying the BCs. It does not give a steady state however because of the +u term. But it does remove the inhomogeneous BC without adding too much extra complexity to the PDE proper.